# Time machine was interrupted - how to make it resume?

Tags: time-machine

Time machine was running for the first time and it was NINE hours into the job, when it got stopped (I inadervently removed the usb connection).

Is there any way to get it to resume?

**UPDATE**  The issue was that the Time Machine icon was not in my Dock - so I did not have option to right click which is where the "Back up now" option lives.

Comment: Click on Time Machine icon and the Backup Now.

Comment: @jherran  thx see update to the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Time Machine icon in your menu bar (top of your screen), go into System Preferences, select Time Machine, and click the "Show Time Machine in menu bar" checkbox.

Click the icon that appears in your menu bar and select "Back Up Now".